# rroReturn type method is missing, YES_NO_OPTION cannot be resolved some errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I made a program to identify the square, square root, cube of number and reverse of a string I have some errors I don't have an idea to fix this.

Here's my code below

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FLABWORK3_ABUEL
    {
      static Scanner Scan new = Scanner (System.in);
      public static void main(String[]  args)
      {
      String choice;
      String num1;
      String string;
      String Inverse;

      int choicee, num2, response, length;
      double squareroot;



      do {
          choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Main Menu" + 
      "\n 1. Square of a number" +
      "\n 2. Square root a number" +
      "\n 3. Cube of a number" +
      "\n 4. Length of number" +
      "\n 5. Inverse of a string");

          choicee = Integer.parseInt(choice);

          while (choicee > 5)
          {
              choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter only 1-5!");
          }

          switch (choicee)
          {
          case 1:
          num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an number.");
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
          num2 = num2*num2 ;

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The square of the number: " + num2);
          break;

          case 2:
              num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number.");
              squareroot = Integer.parseInt(num1);
             squareroot = Math.sqrt(squareroot);

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Square root is: " + squareroot);
             break;

          case 3:
              num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number.");
              num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
              num2 = num2*(num2*num2);

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cube is: " + num2);
              break;

          case 4:
              string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence or a word.");
              length = string.length();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The length :  " + "\n" + length + "\n\n" +
              "is:" + string);
              break;

          case 5:
              string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word.");
              length = string.length();
              for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                  Inverse = Inverse + string.charAt(i);

              JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to ry again?"
                      JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                      JOptionPane.Question_Message, null, options, options [0]);

          }
      }
      while (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
  }
}
```

Is it better to do it switch case or if else statement?
Errors are RETURN TYPE METHOD IS MISSING FOR static scanner and the YES_NO_OPTION cannot be resolved

Comment: what is the exact error ?

Comment: This is totally unrelated to your problem, but you should get used to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367): class names should be LikeThis, variables likeThis, etc. For example, if I see something named `Inverse` or `Scan`, I would expect them to be classes, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably you are missing a comma after your "Would you like to ry again?" string in below:

```
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to ry again?"
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
              JOptionPane.Question_Message, null, options, options [0]);
```

It should be:

```
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to ry again?",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
              JOptionPane.Question_Message, null, options, options [0]);
```

Also you defined scanner as below:

```
static Scanner Scan new = Scanner (System.in);
```

Which should be

```
static Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
```

Another thing is i dont see you defined options anywhere. So you might need to declare and initialize it before using in below line:

```
JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to ry again?",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                            options[0]);
```

Note: Java is case sensitive, so Question_Message is not same as QUESTION_MESSAGE.

Comment: Thanks, but when I did that it still has errors it says, option cannot to resolve to a variable, QUESTION cannot resolved or is not a field

Comment: I have modified my answer. Modify accordingly and let us know how it goes.